# Rigged fingers not aligned

Tags: rigging

[image]
Hi, my rigged fingers are going in different directions. Whats the best way to align them all and make them all straight?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the armature, but I'm guessing the bone rotation is wrong.

Comment: select them and recalculate the bone roll of them with CTRL+N and select one the options to reorient the rotation of the bones in edit mode...